# Best way to sync data from ExactTarget to Magento?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, data-synchronization

We was able to sync the data from Magento to ExactTarget using the ET API and extending Magento.

Now we need to do the opposite.
So If an user unsubscribe or modify his data from the ExactTarget landing pages, we need to sync this data to Magento. Probably calling the Magento API from the landing page.

Is possible create a PHP landing page?
Or witch is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You may think this solution is "hack-tastic" but this is how I've accomplished something like this before.  Keep in mind that landing pages are not designed to function like server pages, so they have very limited server functionality.

1. Design an algorithm outside of ET, living withing your API, to do the sync-ing.  You read that correctly, not on the landing page.
2. Create a landing page within ET.  Then, wire up an ajax call to call the URL you made, from ET to your algorithm. I'd recommend the AMPscript call HTTPGet to do it as the most secure.  You could use clientside javascript as well, but it is less secure (but you can do things like post, which you cannot do with AMPscript).

That should do what you need.